# Showing identity with the integers modulo

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given the set $S_m=\{[\frac{k(k+1)}{2}]_m\}$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$.
Where $[x]_m$ denotes the equivalence class (modm).

I am trying to show that: $S_m=\mathbb{Z}_m$ if and only if $m=2^s$ for some $s \in\mathbb{N}$.

A hint is also given that for each prime $p>2$ there is a $b\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ such that the equation $x^2\equiv b\pmod{p}$ has no solutions.

I've tried using the condition for what m has to equal in order for the identity to hold but I'm quite lost in how to proceed really, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let $t=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$. What expression do you get when you calculate $8t+1$? Can you factorise that?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Yes, so I factorised it as $8t+1=(2k+1)^2$ and which I can see is an odd number but should I then use the hint to show that the both sets are not equal for odd $m$? or how?

Comment: If $m$ is an odd prime, then there is some $b$ that is not a square mod $m$. So you have such a $b$. You can then find $t$ such that $8t+1=b \bmod m$. And so....

Comment: I've given an answer but with the part of the question you've been discussing covered over if you now wish to do that part yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If $m=2^s$**

For $k$ and $l$  residues modulo $2^{s+1}$ suppose $$\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\equiv \frac{l(l+1)}{2}\pmod {2^s}.$$

Then $k(k+1)\equiv l(l+1)\pmod {2^{s+1}}$

i.e. $(k-l)(k+l+1)\equiv 0\pmod {2^{s+1}}$.

Now one of the two factors on the LHS is odd and so the other factor has to be divisible by $2^{s+1}$. So equality occurs if and only if $k+l+1\equiv 0\pmod {2^{s+1}}$. Hence everyone of the $2^{s+1}$ values for $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ is taken precisely twice and so, by the pigeon-hole principle, $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ takes every value modulo $2^s$.

**If $m$ has an odd prime factor $p$**

> Let $b$ be an element such that $x^2\equiv b\pmod p$ cannot be solved.

> Suppose that $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\equiv \frac{b-1}{8}\pmod p$ could be solved. >!Then $(2k+1)^2\equiv b \pmod p$, a contradiction.

Comment: Very nice, and those two cases for m cover all cases? Also how did you get to supposing that the LHS should be congruent to precisely (b-1)/8

Comment: Yes - either m is divisible by an odd prime or its a power of 2. Re. (b-1)/8 its doing the invers of what you had looked at. You had multiplied by 8 and added 1 so subtract 1 and divide by 8.

Comment: How do you determine from the last congruence that for every of the 2^(s+1) values for k(k+1)/2 is taken exactly twice?

Comment: They are paired up with each pair being k and -1-k.

Comment: Ohh, I think I finally got it, thank you very much! Do you have any general tips for approaching problems like these?

Comment: One obvious thing is that familiarity with as many ideas as possible is useful. (In this question quadratic residues.) Other than that, always be prepared to do some examples (In this case mod 8 say) just to get a feel for what the problem is about. Good luck!